# Unable to parse int the string value

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to get value of a string into a integer type like bellow

```
private void updateTotalQuantity() {
    int quantity = 0;
    double price=0.0;
    Double totalPrice = 0.0;
    List<ProductDetail> products = mProductsAdapter.getProducts();

    for (ProductDetail product : products) {
        if (product.getQuantity() != null)
        {
            quantity += (Integer.parseInt(product.getQuantity()));
        }
        if (product.getPrice()!=null && product.getQuantity() != null)
        {
            price = Double.parseDouble(product.getPrice());
            totalPrice = totalPrice + (price * Double.parseDouble(product.getQuantity()));
        }

    }
    totalQty.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
    totalOrder.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
}
```

When I run my application the app crashes at point  `quantity += (Integer.parseInt(product.getQuantity()));` with execption message

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

How can I get rid of this ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you get rid of this by performing checks on valid values. "null" can not be parsed to a valid numeric int value, because it isn't a valid numeric value. also: "null" and null are not the same

Comment: Why is the quantity of a product represented as `String`? Does it contain any units or abbreviated numbers (1k, 2m or anything like that)? And of course it must be initialized before you can parse it…

Comment: You better (also) check `if (!product.getQuantity().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))…`

Comment: @deHaar no it just contain the quantity like `1,2,3,.... n`

Comment: Whatever the intent was, the string `"null"` somehow did get there, and you attempted to do a `null` check for some reason. Just `"null" != null` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Looks like you're writing the String `"null"` (not `null`) into the `quantity` field of `ProductDetail`. But we can only guess, so you should add that class to your question and show us, where `quantity` gets written to. Why is `quantity` even a string value and not numeric in the first place?

Comment: @Moeez It appears more like `"1", "2", … , "null"`…

Comment: The `ProductDetail` class appears to be storing numbers as Strings and allowing the inclusion of a String`"null"` to be included in Lists of Strings.  This is a design choice that requires you to jump through hoops to handle the data safely.  If that data model is out of your control then consider writing some utility methods to pull the values into the expected type (e.g. int, double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a null-check in

```java
if (product.getQuantity() != null)
```

but your string is initialized and its value actually is `"null"` as a string. Wherever your data is coming from, the Adapter most likely parses empty fields into `"null"` instead of `null`.

Either, you check against `"null"`, too:

```java
if (product.getQuantity() != null && product.getQuantity() != "null")
```

or you change the adapter so that it actually returns `null` on an empty field.